# Getting data with nodeJs with or without php

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb

Lately I was watching a lot nodeJS tutorials and from one live chat app with nodeJs and mongo db the user logs in and send the message, insert in database and output in real time to all users.

Is that secured enough or should we use php as well?

Comment: It does not matter what language you use.  You can make either environment very secure or very insecure.  It all depends upon your code.  Many large commercial sites use node.js so it can be made plenty secure and PHP has no particular advantage or disadvantage relative to node.js.  So, in essence your question doesn't really make sense as worded.  A choice of programming language does not really have anything to do with how secure your app is or isn't.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time ^_^

Comment: @Sky Earn 20 reps and then you can go ask such questions in chatrooms.